# password from login form and hashed password in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to compare the submitted password from the login form and the encrypted password stored in the database as follows,

```
$password=crypt($_POST['password']);
//....
$query="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (name='$name' AND pass='$password' AND Activation IS NULL)";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(!$result){}
else
{
   $numRow=mysql_num_rows($result) or die ("ROW QUERY FAILS".mysql_error());
   if ($numRow != 0)
   {

   }
   else
   {
      //ERROR msg is called here
   }
}
```

The ERROR msg is called, is my sql statement incorrect ?

EDIT: I have checked all sql_query, and it works fine, only the second (nested) else clause is shown as error that I have not activated my account or my password is incorrect. I check the output of the password in the submitted form and it is, after encrypted with crypt function, not the same as the one in the database. Is this the feature (timing and seeded) of randomness ? I have no idea about base encoding/decoding, I work on a 64 bit machine, but I don't think this offers anything related I may need to consider. Still I need more hints to get this work. Thanks again for any ideas.

Comment: May be you have to encode the password - http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: hi could you care to explain the use of the `or` after mysql_num_rows() ? i had a hard time understanding why it's there

Comment: Please don't do this. I would make my password `SOMETHING'; DROP TABLE mytable; --` and enjoy it.

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())`.

Comment: Quite a few things you could try. Place ` signs around your table and column names. Place your connection link in your query to make sure it is using the right connection. Echo the entire query to see if it looks right. Compare the $password generated to the one stored in the database. Make sure your database field is long enough to fit in the full hash and it is not being cut off. And finally, do what @KristianAntonsen has stated above.

Comment: @Borealid How exactly would you do that when the password has been run through `crypt`? `crypt` output does not even contain `'`'s.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen All right, betcha `$name` came from POST as well. I don't understand why people don't use PDO - it's been around forever, and is straight better than embedding variables into a query string...

Comment: I assume you have cut out some of your code, as @Borealid is saying, it would be very easy to inject into this query. Make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape your strings and prevent injections. Not necessary on the password as it has been encrypted.

Comment: @Borealid Because 90% of all PHP/MySQL tutorials out there were written prior to PHP 5.1.

Comment: @ianace, you can look up function die in php manual, it looks like if then else statement but is stricter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are dying on the 0 rows result.
Check this code:

```
0 or die("ERROR");
```

This will have same behavior than having a resultset with 0 rows.

You should move your `or die` to the `mysql_query` line.

Comment: Yes I did, but I have got no error produced at that line of code.

Comment: If you encoding the password with mysql funciton your query should include PASSWORD() function. Maybe that?

Comment: There is no reason to use `PASSWORD()`. @user1151711, if you perform the query and nothing gets selected, nor do you get any output, that simply means nothing in the table matches what you're looking for. How can you be certain the row you're trying to get exists?

Comment: Yeap there is no reason to use password if you using crypt (but was not in the original post, hehe). Anyway, Kristian got a point there, the else should not be an error thats the case when user and pass doesn't match to login. (Anyway remove the die in the num row.)